# Touch Selection on mobile fires move event

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

When selecting an object on a mobile device with a touch a move event is instantly fired and the object shifts.

Is there a way do set a delay on these touch selection events so that a user must either hold the object for a few milliseconds before dragging or had to select the object a second time to drag?